# build a docker image that can use LLVM to compile ROS projects

Tags: docker, llvm, ros

I intend to build a Docker image that could use LLVM to compile ROS project code. According to Docker's official document https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ that it's better to avoid multiple services in one container. LLVM and ROS both got their Docker Image, how to compose these two into one and ship it together?

Comment: Have you checked the docker-compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/)? Maybe that will fit your need. It will not create one container but will allow you to manage multiple containers in one deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update (2019.12.13):

If all you want to do use `clang` within the official ROS docker images, you can do something like this:

```
FROM ros:melodic
RUN apt-get -y install clang-6.0
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/c++ c++ $(command -v clang++-6.0) 1000
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc  cc  $(command -v clang-6.0)   1000
```

You can do this because the official ROS images inherit from Ubuntu images which use `update-alternatives` to manage how generic commands (e.g., C/C++ compilers) map to the packages that provide them. In brief, the calls to `update-alternatives` will install various symlinks such that `/usr/bin/cc` and `/usr/bin/c++` both (eventually) point to `clang-6.0` and `clang++-6.0`, respectively.

For detail on how `update-alternatives` works, refer to its [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/update-alternatives.1.html).

Original answer follows.

---

You have a few strategies available to you:

## Combine `Dockerfile`s

If you have access to *both* `Dockerfile`s, then try combining the content therein into one `Dockerfile`. You'll have to choose a single `FROM` instruction, but other instructions can be combined in the manner of your choosing.

## Change the `FROM` on one

If you have access to *only one* `Dockerfile`, then try changing its `FROM` instruction to inherit from the other image. E.g., the `ros:kinetic-ros-core-xenial` image inherits from `ubuntu:xenial`; try changing it to inherit from, say,  `reaverproject/llvm`.

## `ADD` both tarballs

If you have access to *neither* `Dockerfile`, then you'll have to reverse-engineer a bit. Start by creating a "noop" container from each image and `export`ing a filesystem tarball therefrom. I.e., do...

```
$ docker container run --name noop-foobar foobar sh -c 'exit 0'
$ docker container export --output foobar.tar noop-foobar
$ docker container rm noop-foobar
```

...substituting "foobar" as necessary.

Once you have exported both filesystem tarballs, create a "base image" by `ADD`ing them to a `scratch` image:

```
FROM scratch
ADD llvm.tar
ADD ros.tar
...
```

It's very likely you'll have to manually resolve conflicts between filesystem tarballs to get the base image working as intended.

References:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/
- https://hub.docker.com/_/ros
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_export/
- https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/#create-a-simple-parent-image-using-scratch

Comment: Much appreciated the suggestions. Another side-question is that, is complexity or the number of conflicts remain constant no matter which 2 services that I composite?

Comment: @isPrime, your suspicions are correct; any conflicts inherent to the combination are independent of the combining technique. However, more transparency is better; i.e., Dockerfiles are easier than filesystem tarballs.